# How can I change PATH?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

Im trying to use git for my very first project on terminal but it says `zsh: command not found: git` so I tried to download git by downloading homebrew first but guess what it says `zsh: command not found: curl`. So apparently all commands is not working on my terminal and I have no idea why.

I also tried this `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`  but this is only temporary.

How Can I fix my PATH??

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS Catalina, you can define the PATH [environment variable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) in the [`~/.zshrc`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files) file with:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

you can then add more entries to an existing PATH environment variable with:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I tried to run ~/.zshrc and it says zsh: permission denied: I don't know what to do

Comment: Run `sudo chown yourusername  ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I tried it and it says sudo command not found

Comment: Run `su`. Enter your password, then `chown <yourusername> /Users/<yourusername>/.zshrc`